# "python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1

Tags: python-3.x, failed-installation

I'm new to python and have been trying to install some packages with pip. I always get this error message though:

```
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zj8nvth6\pdfminer\pdfminer\__init__.py", line 5
    print __version__
                    ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\App
Data\Local\Temp\pip-build-zj8nvth6\pdfminer\

[The Error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed7J7.jpg)

Any Suggestions ?

Note : I tried installing pdfminer with "python -m pip install pdfminer" and also by downloading the package from online in which I did not get any error but still could not use it properly ; have updated my setup tools with "python -m pip install -U pip setuptools "

Comment: `pip install pdfminer2` worked for me in python 3. Now, I am calling usual `from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager` etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to install a python 2 package to a python 3 environment.

Syntax for `print` in python 2 didn't require parenthesis, but in python 3 it does, and that's why you can't install the package

Comment: I too had the same idea. But it didn't workout when I tried installing the package from "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k".

Isnt pip install command intelligent enough to find the appropriate module for the python I am running ? or Is there any other way to communicate this to pip ? I find pip more appropriate !

Comment: Its not the same ! As I said earlier it didnt show any error, But I just didnot get few functions of pdfminer, like "PDFPage" and stuff. So i just assumed that the installation was not complete or proper !

Comment: @ykrrishna the official GitHub page of the project (https://github.com/goulu/pdfminer) suggests that you should install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer.six/ if you're using Python 3. You might want to try that.

Comment: Am still facing the troubles. 

the installation results in the creation of a folder named "pdfminer.six-20160614-py3.5.egg" and the "pdfminer" folder stays within it.
Is it how it is supposed to be ?

There are some other instances where such .egg folder and also the module folder exist but they are two separate folders not within one another. (This is for a different library file ofcourse !)

Comment: @ykrrishna you might want to try to install it with pip by using `pip install pdfminer.six`

Comment: I dono. There is still no change in the folder hierarchy, but the piece of code that i had for reading the contents worked ! Thanks anyways. Now my goal of fetching a particular data is a little closer ! :)